# How do I set width of custom subview to be 1/3rd of parent UIView which does not have width constraint?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom parent UIView (Say `PView`) which is defined by Left,Right,Top and Bottom constraints. Now I want to add a custom subview (say `SView`) to the `PView` with width equal to MIN of 200 and 1/3rd of `PView`.

I have the updateConstraints method in my `PView` class where I update the location constraints for `SView`. However, I am not sure how can I set its size, because I don't have the widthConstraint of `PView`?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by proportional width feature in storyboard with Autolayout.

Give you PView a proportional width to a ratio of 1:3 to your superView(SView).
Parent View Constraint
[image: Orange Super View(SView)]

Child/SubView View Constraint 
[image: Red Sub View]

How to Give Proportional Constraint? 
You set ParentView and ChildView with equal width then double click on width constraint and set a ratio of 1:3. Width will always be 1/3 of parent view

[image: Proportional Width Constraint]

Coding Approach

```
[self.yourview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:self.yourview
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.yourview
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              multiplier:(self.yourview.frame.size.height / self.yourview.frame.size.width)
                              constant:0]];
```

Comment: I am doing this via code. Is there a way to specify 1:3 when using NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: and NSLayout visualConstraints?

Comment: I have update the question. Would be nice if you could answer the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent view's constraint should be like : `top,leading,trailing,bottom`

Your subview's constraints should be like : `top,leading,fixed height`

Now select `both view` and set `equal width constraint` and then select that constraint and from `attribute inspector` change it's multiplier to `0.333`.

That's it!

Comment: I have update the question. Would be nice if you could answer the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

try using following code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   sview. frame = CGRectMake(0,0,pview.frame/3,50);

}
```

Comment: This wont work. I am using constraints. using frame with constraints is not a good idea.